# getting started with opencv 2.1

Tags: opencv

I'm very new to opencv. Can anyone suggest a source from where I could start learning about the software. Also I want to do image stitching as a part of my project. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: If you are very new to OpenCV then you'd better start with the latest OpenCV 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

[Books:](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCVBooks)

"**Learning OpenCV**" by Gary Bradsky

"**OpenCV cookbook**"

If you are just beginning, try OpenCV 2.3.1, latest version.

[OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/index.html) has got a collection of nice tutorials for beginners.

Join [OpenCV Yahoo group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/). You can ask your doubts in group or here in stackoverflow also.

Also have a look at samples that comes with OpenCV. That is also a good start.

Comment: I'd avoid "Learning OpenCV" until it is updated to the new C++ interface. Go with "OpenCV cookbook" and the online tutorials instead.

Comment: Yeah, it is true. `Learning OpenCV` is not updated. `Tutorial in OpenCV documentation` is best at present. Still, theoretical explanation in `Learning OpenCV` is good